# Trouble exporting from Eclipse due to dependencies

Tags: android, eclipse

I'm trying to export a project from Eclipse to support Gradle, but running into the problem shown in the screenshot. I've selected all the projects yet it says I have dependency problems. Where else can I specify dependencies?
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Did you try refreshing your whole workspace in Eclipse? Often, this solves many GUI-related problems and may be helpful here as well, since your dialog says "Project Cooper is missing" but you checked it below.

Comment: Okay, then I am sorry for that unhelpful answer. I just remember, that I ran into those kind of problems, too when trying to build my first programs with gradle. For me, it was mostly the customization of the build.gradle file. Have you made sure, that you included all the dependencies in your config? (s. http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/eclipse_plugin.html 38.4.2.2)